# How do I change interrupt priority of serial driver so that it is higher priority than ethernet interrupt?

Tags: serial-port, linux-device-driver

I am running serial port at 460800 baud rate.The data is send continuously. The serial driver data is passed to user space application which sends data using socket to network application.  From time to time, I get serial driver HW Fifo overrun because it is either taking too long to run ISR or other interrupt (I have Ethernet, Serial and gp_timer interrupts only). Also, I think that there are instances in which Ethernet and serial interrupts both are in interrupt queue (My assumption)  and Ethernet driver interrupt takes priority over serial driver interrupt and meanwhile the serial driver HWFIFO overflows.

The moment I disabled the data transfer to network application all the data at the user space received fine. That make me believe that it could be the Ethernet driver which is causing the issue.

I would like to change the priority of serial interrupt so that it gets served ahead of Ethernet driver interrupt. Do you think changing the priority would solve the problem?

I am on Linux 2.6.32 ARMV7.

Comment: You have a real time problem, but you are not using a real time system to solve it. Either look at real time patches for linux, or use a real time OS, or a dedicated bare metal processor to handle the serial port and give you additional buffering.

Comment: @Chris I checked the real time patch option, but not available for 2.6.32, can I still apply patches from 2.6.33 or 2.6.31? which one would be better choice? [link](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/2.6.33/)Also, is there any downside of applying RT patches? What do you think about the level of effort involved? Other question, I have is we are able to read the data without issues on windows machine? that makes me believe that we don't need RT patches. But, I may be wrong, could you please also shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which would version of the patches would be better to try, I would say apply version 2.6.33 first, and if the patches apply without issue, then just use it, if they do not apply then try the 2.6.31 patches.

The downside to the patches is that it makes linux preemptable, so you have to be careful because you never know when you will be swapped out. This means using a mutex to protect data that is shared between threads and things like that. It isn't a big issue if you understand what you are doing.

The reason it works on windows is luck, if you run the test on windows and then heavily load the system does it still work? I doubt it. In a **properly designed** real time system it will always work regardless of system load.